# SMS Never Arrives when sent from T-SQL sp_send_dbmail

Tags: t-sql, sms, sql-server-2008-r2

I can send to email like this "5551112222@messaging.sprintpcs.com" from outlook, and get SMS, but same email doesn't work in T-SQL with sp_send_dbmail.  Any ideas where it might be getting blocked?  Does sp_send_dbmail use SMTP server directly?  Or exchange?

Same code below works fine when I put a normal email address.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = 'DoNotReply_ProdAv_xxxxx.com',     
  @recipients = '5551112222@messaging.sprintpcs.com',
  @subject = 'Test from SQL',
  @append_query_error = 1,
  @query_result_separator = ' '
```

Comment: Similar problem over here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic514505-146-2.aspx.  Comments were: works with some providers, can use a custom clr to make sure you send ascii, or the most practical - just send it to your email with a rule set up to forward from outlook to your sms address.

Comment: Thanks, the forwarding is a great solution for now!